# Active Directory how to make Group Policy to allow users to change their network settings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, security

I have Active Directory 2003 and my users are on Windows XP. How can I set a policy to active network configuration for the users? In other words some users are traveling a lot so I want to give them allow to change network configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can manage the network configuration on a system without having local Administrator rights if you are a member of the "Network Configuration Operators" local group; so you will need to add your domain users to this local group on the machines where they need this specific right.

Whatever is better to do this via group policy or manually depends on if you want those users to have this right on every computer or only on their own one.

Comment: Ok is there a way to add some users to network configuration operators from active directory to avoid go to each PC for example user1 and user2 when they are logon immediately they are inside network configuration operators?

Comment: Yes, you can use the "resticted groups" settings in a group policy.

Comment: There are two options, [Group Policy Restricted Groups](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/using-restricted-groups.html) and [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892%28WS.10%29.aspx) (the last word makes a world of difference) local group settings.  The former is exclusive: if you have anyone in a group that is not specified in the policy, they will get removed every policy refresh, reboot, whatever makes sense first logically. The latter is inclusive and will only add, remove, modify those people specified by policy.

Comment: @alharaka: the second option is only available from Windows Server 2008, the question is about 2003.

Comment: @Massimo: Untrue.  You can install the [Client Side Extensions if you need them on XP and Vista](http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/03/27/group-policy-preferences-not-applying-on-some-clients-client-side-extension-xmllite.aspx).  Domain is not an issue, but the GP Management console version and the admin workstation is. I have done this because the flexibility required in large domain environments where I was in charge of a few OU's, and other domain admins were uncooperative.

Comment: Ok but I want to define user just on specific PC for example I have user1 and I want him to have network access just on PC1 not on all the computers If I do resticted groups it will applied on all computers otherwise I have to create OU for each user but this is a bad idea because the active directory will be mess. So in this case what should I do?

Comment: In this case the easiest approach would be to manually add the user to the local group on his/her computer.